# вопрос по туду листу

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пжл следующее:
1.Как удалить выделенную галочкой (checked) задачу, нажав на кнопу "Удалить"?
2.Как цветом выделить текст выполненной задачи, нажав на кнопу "Выполнено"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <title> Task list </title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/C1.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div>
    <h1>Task list</h1>
     <div class="create_new_todo">
      <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Описание">
      <button class="add">Добавить</button>
      <button class="remove">Удалить</button>
      <button class="clear">Очистить</button>
      <button class="done">Выполнено</button>
     </div>
     <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="todo"></ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="../JS/TASK1.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>

let addMessage = document.querySelector('.message');
let addButton = document.querySelector('.add');
let removeButton = document.querySelector('.remove');
let doneButton = document.querySelector('.done');
let clearButton = document.querySelector('.clear');
let todo = document.querySelector('.todo');

let todoList = [];

if(localStorage.getItem('todo')) {
  todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo'));
  displayMessages();
} 

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(!addMessage.value) return;
  let newTodo = {
    todo: addMessage.value,
    checked: false,
    important: false
  };
todoList.push(newTodo);
displayMessages();
localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todoList));
});

function displayMessages() {
  let displayMessage = '';
  if(todoList.length === 0) todo.innerHTML = '';
  todoList.forEach(function(item, index) {
    displayMessage += `
    <li>
      <input type='checkbox' id='item_${index}' ${item.checked ? 'checked' : ''}>
      <label for='item_${index}' class="${item.important ? 'important' : ''}">${item.todo}</label>
    </li>
    `;
    todo.innerHTML = displayMessage;
  });
}

clearButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   todoList = [];
   displayMessages();
localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todoList));
```

Comment: фигурную скобочку потеряли в `clearButton.addEventListener`

Comment: ...и там же круглую в конце `localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todoList)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
removeButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const checkboxAll = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')];
  checkboxAll.forEach(item => {
    if(item.checked) item.closest('li').remove();
  });
});

doneButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const checkboxAll = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')];
  checkboxAll.forEach(item => {
    if(item.checked) item.closest('li').style.color = 'green';
  });
});
```

Только с localStorage я не стал заморачиваться, там думаю проблем не возникнет

Comment: спасибо, всё работает